The sphere $S^2$ is not a Lie Group
This semester we had a test and I could not answer part b) of the following problem:
a) Show that the tangent bundle of a Lie group $G$ is trivial, i.e., one can identify it with the cartesian product of $G$ and some vector space.
b) Show that the tangent bundle of the sphere $S^2$ is non trivial and therefore $S^2$ does not have the Lie group structure. (You can assume the hairy ball theorem).
My attempt:
a) Recall that the tangent bundle is the disjoint union of all tangent spaces of the manifold. In this particular case $TG=\sqcup_{g \in G} T_gG$. Since $G$ is a Lie group, every tangent space is isomorphic to the tangent space on the identity, then $TG=\sqcup_{g \in G} T_gG=\sqcup_{g \in G} T_eG$, so the tangent bundle is just the disjoint union of copies of the Lie algebra $T_eG$. Then $TG=G\times T_eG$,  which proves the assertion.
b) By the way of contradiction, suppose that we can write $TS^2 \simeq S^2 \times K$, where $K$ is some vector space. Let $X$ be a continuous vector field on the sphere. This is where my problems start. Since a vector field is a section of the tangent bundle I could identify $X\mapsto (\tilde{p},k)$, where $\tilde{p} \in S^2$ and $k \in K$. On the other hand, the hairy theorem asserts that for every continuous vector field $X$, there exists $p \in S^2$ such that $X(p)=0$, but since $\tilde{p} \in S^2$, then $(\tilde{p},k)$ could not be equal to zero. This would be a contradiction.
I feel very uncomfortable with the last part that I wrote in part b). If anyone can point mistakes and provide hints I will be enormously grateful.

You mean $TS^2\cong S^2\times \Bbb R^2$? Then there are two everywhere linearly independent global sections.

You had the right idea for (b) (using the hairy ball theorem), but the execution is botched: in your notation, the HBT says that there exists $p \in S^2$ such that $X(p) = (\tilde{p}, 0)$ (but really there's no point in carrying the $\tilde{p}$ around). Also, everything you wrote for (a) is either true by definition or false, and certainly doesn't assemble into a proof (for a start, you could replace $G$ by any manifold and $T_e G$ by $T_{x_0} G$ for any point $x_0$ and the argument wouldn't change, but the conclusion would be false).

@TedShifrin I did not think about writing it that way, but yes. Also, I edited "vector field" for "vector space". And your answer made think about the following: The tangent space at any point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (right?), then I could write the tangent bundle as you wrote it. I am still processing your sentence "Then there are two everywhere linearly independent global sections." Thanks a lot!

You misunderstood what $X(p) = 0$ means: In your notation, i.e. if $X(p) = (\tilde{p}, k)$, it means that $X(p) = (\tilde{p}, 0)$, not $X(p) = (0, k)$ (here, and implicitly in your questions, $\tilde{p} = p$ for all $p \in S^2$). Of course, by definition of vector field you always have to have $X(p) = (p, k)$, so the condition $X(p) = (0, k)$ doesn't even quite parse.
As for how to use the hairy ball theorem the right way, here's a (big) hint: If the tangent bundle of $S^2$ is trivial, then there is an isomorphism $T S^2 \cong S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ by definition. Can you find a non-vanishing vector field $S^2 \to S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$?

You didn't strictly ask about this, but as I already pointed out in the comments, your proof for part (a) does not work at all. Concretely,

"The tangent bundle is the disjoint union of all tangent spaces of the manifold."

This is true on the level of sets, not on the level of topological spaces, or manifolds, or vector bundles.

"Since $G$ is a Lie group, every tangent space is isomorphic to the tangent space on the identity, then $T_G = \bigsqcup_{g ∈ G} T_g G = \bigsqcup_{g ∈ G} T_e G$, so the tangent bundle is just the disjoint union of copies of the Lie algebra $T_e G$."

This is true, again, on the level of sets. In particular, it's true on any manifold, not just on Lie groups: $T_x M \cong T_y M$ for all $x, y \in M$ (since they're both isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$).
Thus the conclusion $T G \cong G \times T_e G$ is true, but, again, only on the level of sets, and there it holds for all manifolds, so you've shown nothing at all.
If you want a hint, looking at $T_e G$ is not a bad idea, but it's better even to look at $T G|_U$ over some open neighborhood $U$ of $E$ such that $T G|_U$ is trivial, and then study what happens when you multiply with elements of $G$.

Thanks a lot! You gave me a lot to think about. It's amazing how much one can learn from just asking

For (a), use the group law to “drag” a nonzero tangent vector at the identity to every every tangent space: for $g$ in $G$, let $l_g:G\to G$ be left multiplication by $g$, so $l_g(e)=g$ and $l_g$ is a diffeomorphism of $G$. We get the invertible linear map $d(l_g)_e : T_e(G) \to T_g(G)$, so fixing a nonzero $v$ in $T_e(G)$ gives us a nonzero $v_g := d(l_g)_e(v)$ for each $g\in G$. The
map $G \to T(G)$ where $g \mapsto v_g$ is a continuous section that is not the identity (the basepoint) in any tangent space.
As a concrete example, think about the Lie group $S^1$ and how you can drag a nonzero vector based at $(1,0)$ to create a nonzero vector in every tangent space to $S^1$ by rotation (the group law). By orienting all the tangent spaces (lines) so they are perpendicular to $S^1$, do you see how the tangent bundle to $S^1$ can be viewed as an infinite cylinder and how a section formed by dragging a nonzero tangent vector at the identity to all other tangent spaces gives you a circle parallel to $S^1$ and not equal to tue base circle anywhere?
For (b), the tangent bundle to each Lie group has a nonvanishing (nowhere equal to the basepoint) continuous section by (a), but every continuous section of the tangent bundle to $S^2$ vanishes somewhere by the hairy ball theorem, so $S^2$ with its usual manifold structure can’t be given a smooth group law making it a Lie group.  The hairy ball theorem applies to $S^n$ when $n$ is a positive even number, so all such $S^n$ are not Lie groups.  (The group $S^0 = \{\pm 1\}$ is a Lie group with dimension zero.)
The odd-dimensional spheres $S^1$ and $S^3$ are Lie groups (norm-1 elements in the complex numbers and quaternions). When $n > 3$ is odd, $S^n$ is not a Lie group, but this is harder to show than the even-dimesional case because the hairy ball theorem does not apply to odd-dimensional spheres.

Very concise. Thanks a lot. Now I need to order my thoughts and fill in the details
